# Prepare a C++ library full of std::ostream for use in winRT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I have an existing library I would like to use in a new winRT app. The problem is that the library is full of dependencies on std::ostream for logging and other file procedures. Is there a way to get a valid stream from the runtime that I can convert to an stl form? Or do I have to convert it all to use the winRT streams? This would not be desirable because it means it will no longer be portable. Thanks.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: roll your own `std::ostream` or (preferable) `std::streambuf` wrapper around the winRT streams. But since I have no idea about winRT streams, this is just speculation. No idea if it's possible or if has been done already.

Comment: Formally speaking, it's Microsoft's responsibility. The standard says that the standard output stream is named `std::cout`. WinRT may have _additional_ names for it, and possibly different methods for those, but that doesn't take away `std::cout`. Then again, Microsoft and standards...

Answer (score 0):

MFC, COM, ATL, WTL, WRL, C++/CX, and so on are all C++ based, so rather than ostream's working, within (WinRT api based app targetting) Windows Store app containerization the concern is more with target location of data, as elaborated at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh967755.aspx If the target location is outside app's container's capability, then it'll be pointless to rework on streams.

The key call sequence will be like

```
storageFileObj=GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(ref new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/data.file"))
ofstream(storageFileObj->Path->data) //Actually data here is wchar*, while ofstream will want char*
```